# Index based Nested JSON Object

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm new to JSON and MongoDB Schema and I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I want to store userId as an index and then it's location co-ordinates as the value of that user's location (Using geoJSON her) corresponding to that index ("userId").

Here's my MongoDB Schema.

```
const locationSchema = new Schema({
    userId:
        {
            geometry: geoSchema
        }
});
```

Furthermore,

```
const geoSchema = new Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    date: { 
        type:Date, 
        default:Date.now 
    }
});
```

& Here is my post request

```
{
    "userId":
            {
               "geometry":{ 
                "coordinates": [
                    1.9,
                    2
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            }
        }
}
```

Note: If I change "userId" to actual userId i.e. 12345 etc. it'll not work.

Problem is, I am not able to set userId ( which is parent object) value. I did this thing while using Firebase API but here I'm not able to figure out how to do so.
The advantage that I'm seeing with this approach is that I can store the location of the user, again and again, corresponding to user's id instead of creating storing it as a new object each time.
Hopefully, I'm making sense here.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You want an array on the geometry object, the schema should be like :

```
{
    userId: String,
    geometry: [ geoSchema ]
}
```

Then you can "push" items to an existing object https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html

Your mongo query would look like :

```
db.collection.update(
   { user: "12345" },
   { $push: {
       "geometry":{ 
            "coordinates": [
                1.9,
                2
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        } 
   }
)
```

**Original reply**

You need a field for your `userId` in your schema.
For exemple it can be :

```
{
    userId: String
    geometry: geoSchema
}
```

Then your POST request would look like :

```
{
    "userId": "12345"
    {
       "geometry":{ 
        "coordinates": [
            1.9,
            2
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Postman gives error when I try to do post request like this. I had to use comma (,) after userId but still I'm not achieving what I wanted. It will be taken as a single object each and every time.

Comment: Yeah sure, I forgot the comma.
Do you want to append a new geometry to a specific object ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want and I should be able to set value of that object i.e. userId.

Comment: As I undertstand your problem, you have to modify your schema.

Comment: I've updated my response, does it better fits your problem ?

Comment: Thanks @Bameza. It was of great help.